# How can user classes be made COMVisible in an assembly which references them in a web reference?

Tags: vb.net, vba, web-services, wcf, com

My end goal is to call a web service from VBA in Microsoft Access 2010.  I've decided that the best way to achieve this is to write a COM Visible assembly to consume the web service and act as a bridge between Microsoft Access (VBA 7) and the web service.

I've tried with both an ASP.Net Web Application/Service and a WCF Service Application, using Visual Studio 2010.

This solution works great for simple data types such as strings, integers, etc., but custom classes just aren't visible from the application referencing the COM visible assembly.

How can they be made COM Visible?

Apologies if none of this makes any sense - my brain's fried!

Comment: Post the code you have so far.

Comment: Are the classes decorated with `<ComVisible(True)>`?

Comment: @dee, I'll try to post some code tomorrow.

Comment: @Comintern, the classes defined in my assembly are decorated with <ComVisible(True), Guid("some guid"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)>.  Those classes aren't the issue - the issue is that I'm trying to pass classes defined in the web service as parameters.  I had wondered if I could simply add <ComVisible(True)> to the classes in the WCF Web Application... but I doubt that those decorations would be passed from the web application to the service reference generated by WSDL...?  I suppose I could manually add those decorations to the generated code?

Comment: Are you following the guidelines described in [Walkthrough: Creating COM Objects with Visual Basic](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x66s8zcd(v=vs.110).aspx)?